Synthesizable RTL code to detect X on a bus
Learnt that === operator is non synthesizable.
I have a situation to write RTL code where it detects 'x' on a bus and replaces it with '0'.
Do not comprehend to achieve it without using === operator. Can someone help by providing synthesizable code to do the same.

'x' cannot be detected - it's not a state distinct from '0' or '1', it's just a state that conveys no meaningful information.  (If you could detect 'x', you'd have trinary logic, rather than binary!)
